# background threads in flask

Tags: python, flask, socket.io

I'm trying to run a function in the background as a thread in flask, but the whole server just stops.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from flask_cors import CORS
from threading import Thread
import time

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
app.debug = True
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")

number = 0

def rising_number():
    global number
    while True:
        number = number + 1
        time.sleep(1)

set_number = Thread(target=rising_number)
set_number.start()

def send_number():
    while True:
        socketio.emit('message', number)
        time.sleep(0.1)

@socketio.on('connect')
def connection():
    send_thread = Thread(target=send_number)
    send_thread.start()

socketio.run(app,port=5000,host='0.0.0.0')
```

I'm trying to make the `rising_number` function run in the background, so the number displayed on the frontend will be the same for everyone on the website.

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example of your problem. What libraries are you using? What is the client code doing? There's no one for someone besides you to take your code and debug and test it without those pieces.

Comment: @TeddyBearSuicide i added the libraries, and the frontend is just recieving and console logging the message

Comment: Great that helps. Please post minimal amount of code for the frontend. Again hard for someone to come in see this and then have to write some frontend code to test with. And what do you mean by the server just stops? What exactly is happening and what is expected to happen?